# VBA Value Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA. Basically, my code attempts to output a classification based on the maximum value in an area column, which is has several categories. The logic seems right but I keep on getting a #VALUE! error. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Public Function luclass(NAPS As Double) As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim c As Range, rng As Range
Dim maxclass As String
Dim maxshape As Double
     With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LandUseClass2")
     lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
     maxclass = "Blank"
     maxshape = 0
     For Each c In .Range("B2:B650" & lastrow)
          If c.Value = NAPS Then
               If .Range("F" & c.Row).Value > maxshape Then
                   .Range("C" & c.Row).Text = maxclass
               End If
          End If
     Next c
     End With
     luclass = maxclass
End Function
```

Comment: How is this function called? If it's a User-Defined Function (UDF) called by a cell formula, you can't do that. A function takes input, computes stuff, and produces an output - no side-effects: a function can't modify other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `.Range("B2:B650" & lastrow)`  to `.Range("B2:B" & lastrow)`
2. Change `.Range("C" & c.Row).Text = maxclass` to `.Range("C" & c.Row).Value = maxclass` as `.text` is a readonly property.

You are getting the `#Value` error because you are trying to write to a range in a function.

Use a `Sub` instead of a `Function` or explain what exactly are you tying to achieve and we will take it form there :)

```
Public Sub luclass(NAPS As Double)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it's saying that the initial "Public Sub luclass(NAPS As Double) As String" - that the As String part is an expected end of statement?

Comment: Oh I suppose subs usually don't take an input?

Comment: @Melanie subs can take input, but just get rid of the final `As String`, so the signature is simply: `Public Sub luclass(NAPS As Double)`.